# Combining multiple WebSockets endpoints in Java EE 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

I use GlassFish Server 4.1 / Java EE 7. Thus, the Tyrus WebSocket implementation is readily available out of the box.

There is a scenario in a Java EE application where users and an admin perform CRUD operations collectively. The "insert" operation is performed by registered users and the rest of the operations are handled by an administrator as and when required.

For example, feedback is submitted (thus, inserted through its associated JPA entity `Feedback`) by registered users (only after signing in). "Update" (basically only `testimonials`) and "delete" are performed by an administrator as and when required (in his own session).

Therefore, these operations are performed in different sessions which require different authentications/authorizations. For this to be so, two different WebSockets endpoints are required such as,

```
@ServerEndpoint("/Admin/Push")
```

and

```
@ServerEndpoint("/User/Push")
```

Instead of using two different classes such as,

```
@ServerEndpoint("/Admin/Push") // This is a secured endpoint requiring admin's privileges.
public final class AdminPush {

    private static final Set<Session> sessions = new LinkedHashSet<Session>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String text) {
        // Notify all users.
        // Since modifications to entities are done on the server side,
        // it is basically another synchronized static method notifying all users.
    }
}
```

and

```
@ServerEndpoint("/User/Push") // This is a secured endpoint requiring user's privileges.
public final class UserPush {

    private static final Set<Session> sessions = new LinkedHashSet<Session>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        sessions.add(session);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        sessions.remove(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String text) {
        // Notify all users.
        // Since modifications to entities are done on the server side,
        // it is basically another synchronized static method notifying all users.
    }
}
```

is it allowed to combine them into a single class such as?

```
@ServerEndpoint("/Admin/Push")
@ServerEndpoint("/User/Push")
public final class Push {}
```

Theoretically, this is just one thought to say whether it is allowed to combine them in such an imaginary way or not. Practically, it is obviously a compile-time error as `@ServerEndpoint` is not a repeatable annotation.

In either of the above cases, users are notified, when something is modified in `Feedback` JPA entities (real time update through WebSockets) either by an admin or users. `Feedback` is publicly available to all users including anonymous but can only be submitted by registered users (It is also periodically updated but that's a story apart).

Comment: Did you get any solution to this I also want to do something similar

Comment: @Teocci : Sadly no. Instead I created separate endpoints as shown in the snippets.

Comment: I was thinking and I end up with a [possible solution](http://pastebin.com/fiSvAkmv), please let me know if there is any drawback

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can do something like:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/{profile}/push")
public final class Push {}
```

Or from a business separation point of view, you should create one or more classes to manage sessions or common operations, and the entry point classes only needs to call these common methods. Something like:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/admin/push")
public final class Admin {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // Call session manager
    }
}

@ServerEndpoint("/user/push")
public final class User {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // Call session manager
    }
}

public class SessionManager {
    // Your methods
}
```

Just a couple of ideas.

Comment: The first approach using `javax.websocket.server.PathParam` cannot be used as it can allow anything in the path parameter. Any user can therefore readily forge a connection to that endpoint using the JavaScript API. (It is no longer secure, if the specified URI is allowed to be dynamic).